# Getting terms matching wildcard in ElasticSearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

When I have an ElasticSearch index, how can I get a list of terms that match a wildcard query?

E.g. for the query `Cont*ct`, I would like to get results of `contact`, `contract`, `contradicting` etc. Given that terms in the result are present in documents of the index.

Answer (score 0):

As your query is "Cont*ct" the term "contradicting" would not be returned as there is no match for "ing".
In this case I could add * to the end of the search term.

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "text": {
        "value": "cont*ct*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```